# Calling multiple XML files

Tags: objective-c, xml, ipad, nsxmlparser

In my application(iPad application) I have 5 folders and inside of each folder i have one XML file. My question is, How can I call all .xml files, in my appDelegate

I have file1.xml, file2.xml, file3.xml, file4.xml,file5.xml (it's a requirement)

for call or adding Path for file1 xml I have this code:

```
NSString *xml = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file1" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xml];
NSXMLParser *Parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:Data];
file1 *parser = [[file1 alloc] initXMLParser];
```

but how can I have all 5 in my appDelegate class?

and do I need to create specific parser class for each or since all information and tags are the same I just need to add all in my appDelegate

**EDIT:**

I have to call them from their folder I cann"t change the structure for example

Folder1/file1.xml

Folder2/file2.xml

Folder3/file3.xml and so on

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to instantiate an `NSXMLParser` object for each XML file you're parsing. The simple way to load the XML files is as kimsnarf says: use a for loop and load them in order. If they're in the bundle (which they appear to be), I'd stick them in a specific path under "Resources," like "Resources/SpecialXMLJunk" and just load them by iterating over the results of something like `URLsForResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:` (used to get the XML files out of "Resources/SpecialXMLJunk"). So, pseudocode-ish, probably something like this:

```
NSArray *xmlResourceURLs = [mainBundle
                            URLsForResourcesWithExtension: @"xml"
                            subdirectory: xmlResourcesPath];
foreach (NSURL *xmlURL in xmlResourceURLs)
    [self loadJunkXMLAtURL: xmlURL];
```

Comment: Thanks but since I cann"t change the folder format (as a requirement) and each of them are located in their folder,  what do you recommend ?

Comment: but since the folder name is the same just number changes can i use something like pathForResource:Folder%d/file%d and ofType:@"xml" ??

Comment: I recommend that if you have specific requirements then you not use examples and give those specific requirements. As for what you can use, only you'd know since you're the one with the actual requirements. Read documentation if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a for-loop and load/parse the files one by one. You should store the parsed data somewhere anyway (in a cache or database) so you don't need to hold on to the files and parsers after parsing. Retrieve data from the cache/database instead.

Comment: Thanks but I need to call them from folders it's the requirement , It"s just a test application, and they want to have it like this b-(